# grails 3 load image external folder

Tags: java, image, grails, resources, asset-pipeline

I would like to load images from an external folder of the same server were is deployed the grails app. Let say in linux - user home.

I've found many articles on the web but without success.

My `.gsp` code is attempts:

```
<asset:image src="libs/test/1.jpg"  alt=""/>
<asset:image src="images/2.jpg"  alt=""/>
<img src="${asset.assetPath(src: '13123.jpg')}" />
<img src="\home\user\img\Desert.jpg" />
```

I need something like:

```
<img src="${userhome}/image.jpg" />
```

where userhome is a predifined folder.

And another question using asset pipeline plugin I get this error:

```
Byte array resource [resource loaded from byte array] cannot be resolved to URL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't point to external file with **asset** tag. But you can retrieve the file from the filesystem and "attach" it to response as a byte array, example of a controller action:

```
def getImage() {
    byte[] imageInBytes = imageService.getImage()
    response.with{
        setHeader('Content-length', imageInBytes.length.toString())
        contentType = 'image/jpg' // or the appropriate image content type
        outputStream << imageInBytes
        outputStream.flush()
    }
}
```

Service logic may look like that:

```
byte[] getImage() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(new File('/path/to/file')), "jpg", baos)
    baos.toByteArray()
}
```

And finally the **img** tag on your gsp:

```
<img ... src="${createLink(controller: 'imageController', action: 'getImage')}" />
```

May be you'll want to play with ids and URL Mappings to retrieve the particular images with the service logic.

Comment: OK I tester and its working. I was thinking if I want to build a gallery and uploading images by grails only what approach is optimal with asset pluggin or external? Thank you

Comment: It's better not to use assets for galleries. Because you'll always lose the images when redeploying the app.

Comment: OK thank you. I'll try to implemented with your example. I always have an option using the DB to store images - but I don't like the idea very much.

Comment: I have the similar challenge at the moment. I'm trying to redesign the system to store images using mongoDB (to avoid filesystem storages) and use MySQL for other data.

Do you have any suggestions or useful links regarding to this problem?

Comment: I was using this one: https://grails.org/wiki/Simple%20Avatar%20Uploader and it was working fine for me with grails 3

Comment: Btw I wanted to ask you why do you want to redesign from the file-system to the DB?

Comment: For cloud/clustering purpose etc.